# Regex to delete two (or more) search items leaving the content between them

Tags: regex

There are two search terms which I need to delete whilst leaving the content between them present, and I'd like to use one regex for that if possible. The scheme looks like this:

```
(?<=LOOKBEHIND) SEARCH_TERM_#1 {CONTENT_TO_BE_LEFT} SEARCH_TERM_#2 {END_OF_DOCUMENT}
```

PS: Do you know if there is a regex sign for end of document like there exists `$` for end of line ?

Thanks, all contributions will be appreciated.

PSS: The actual text is as follows:

```
</BODY></HTML><FILE CREATED ON 0:32:33 Feb 24, 2009>{several empty lines before the end of document}
```

What is to stay after deletion is `<0:32:33 Feb 24, 2009>`

Comment: A sample data would be nice.

Comment: `$` will match the end of the document by default and will match the end of the line only when the multiline option is on.

Comment: hjpotter92, the actual text is as follows:</BODY></HTML><FILE CREATED ON 0:32:33 Feb 24, 2009>{several empty lines before the end of document}

What is to stay after deletion is <0:32:33 Feb 24, 2009>

Comment: @Aquinax You would probably be better off with an html parser in this case.

Comment: Simple regex searches is all I can master in this area. I've heard about html parsers and also about a learning curve involved in using them. Unfortunately, I've no time for new learning curves now and thus for html parsers, I guess, as well. THanks for suggesting it, Jerry, though AND for editing my post! ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the two search terms then you can simply capture the rest *(what should be left intact)* in capturing group and then use a replacement string like the following :

```
$1
```

So you need to modify your regex like this:

```
(?<=LOOKBEHIND) SEARCH_TERM_#1 (CONTENT_TO_BE_LEFT) SEARCH_TERM_#2 {END_OF_DOCUMENT}
```

Regarding the end-of-document, actually `$` refers to the end-of-string or document by default, if you want it to match end-of-lines you will have to turn on a special regular expression modifier, usually called multi-line mode.

I think you can do it with the following expression:

```
.*?(?<=CREATED ON )([^>]+)>.*
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jI0oU8)

This example is in PHP, you need to turn on the dot-matches-newline mode so everything till the end of the document is replaced.

Comment: Thanks Sniffer. I'll give it a try and later tell about results - my PC is too busy with other stuff right now.

Comment: @Aquinax You are welcome, I have made some modifications to my answer to cover you last edit.

Comment: Sniffer, I've set (?<=</HTML>)<CREATED ON (\d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d \w{3} \d\d, \d{4}>)\n to be searched for and replaced with <$1 and it did the trick! I thought of using searh and replace instead of search and delete, but I did not know that $1 represents capturing group in search and replace operations. That is valuable information - thanks for it and for helping me with the regex! Very much obliged! And have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mention language, you can adapt following python code

```
>>> re.sub(r'SEARCH_TERM_1(.*?)SEARCH_TERM_2',r'\1','SEARCH_TERM_1okSEARCH_TERM_2',flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    'ok'
>>> re.sub(r'SEARCH_TERM_1(.*?)SEARCH_TERM_2',r'\1','SEARCH_TERM_1okSEARCH_TERM_2   SEARCH_TERM_1okSEARCH_TERM_2',flags=re.MULTILINE|r\
    e.DOTALL)
    'ok   ok'
```

Comment: I don't understand Python, FUD. Thanks, though.

Comment: its like saying replace all matching regex param1 in text param3 by regex param2 using flags param 4. :)

Comment: FUD, I hope you're not taking a piss at me because I don't understand Python-shmython. Didn't get your last post.

Answer (score 0):

This will erase everything except the part between the search terms:

```
Regex.Replace(input, string.Format("(.*{0})(.*)({1}.*)", search1, search2),"$2", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

EDIT:

to do exactly what you specified in the comment:

```
var search1 = "ON ";
var search2 = ">";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, string.Format("(.*{0})(.*{1})(.*)", search1, search2), "<$2", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Matus, that's too complicated for me. A simple regular expression is all what would meet my needs and also all what would not exceed my capabilities .. )) Thanks for replying though!

Comment: but that IS a simple regular expression